Need Help Reading CSV File & Cloning From LineRenderer Prefab
I'm pretty new at C# and Unity and I'm trying to visualize a 3D network in. I have 2 CSV files: one containing 3 columns of number, each representing an X, Y, and Z coordinate for a 3D scatterplot, where each row is one point in 3D space. The other CSV file contains 2 columns, which respectively represent the start and end point of a line connecting the points in the first file. It takes the indexes of the points from the first file and matches them together, forming edges. (ex: point 1 might be [3.56, 2.98, 7.12] and point 2 might be [4.79, 2.10, 4.68], an row in the second CSV file might look like [1, 2], representing an edge).
I've already successfully created a sphere prefab that "graphs" each data point, using a script that reads the CSV data for the points. I want to do the same thing for each line between the data points.
Screenshot of data visualization:

This is my script to read the edge data, but I'm not sure why I'm getting a "Failed to load CSV file" error even though my edge CSV file is clearly not empty.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
public class EdgeReader
{
    static string SPLIT_RE = @",(?=(?:[^""]*""[^""]*"")*(?![^""]*""))";
    static string LINE_SPLIT_RE = @"\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r";
    static char[] TRIM_CHARS = { '\"' };
    public TextAsset _edgeFile;
 
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> Read(string file)
    {
        var list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        TextAsset data = Resources.Load(file) as TextAsset;
        // Debug.Log("EdgeReader_Null");
        if (data == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load CSV file: " + file);
            return list;
        }
 
        var lines = Regex.Split(data.text, LINE_SPLIT_RE);
 
        if (lines.Length <= 1) return list;
 
        var header = Regex.Split(lines[0], SPLIT_RE);
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var values = Regex.Split(lines[i], SPLIT_RE);
            if (values.Length == 0 || values[0] == "") continue;
 
            int source, target;
            if (!int.TryParse(values[0], out source) || !int.TryParse(values[1], out target))
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Failed to parse edge at line " + i);
                continue;
            }
 
            var edge = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            edge["source"] = source;
            edge["target"] = target;
 
            list.Add(edge);
        }
        return list;
    }
}

Any thoughts?

why not use an existing CSV library rather than reinventing the wheel?

Id ask, where is said file, and whats it called?

Show us the code you are using to call this function, what value are you passing for the file path?

Your problem is in this line here
TextAsset data = Resources.Load(file) as TextAsset;

One of two things is happening, either your filepath held in your file variable is not pointing to a valid file that can be loaded, or the value returned by Reasources.Load is not castable to TextAsset, either way this line is returning null. Check your file is correct and in the correct location, and you are passing the correct path into your function.
I don't use this function often myself but from reading the docs it seems it takes a type parameter, like this Reasources.Load<TextAsset>(), which would give you a better error message if your types are incompatible.
